# Question on Transforming the Sum of Two Infinite Series into the Sum of Two Exponentials Using Maclaurin Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am analyzing the differential equation, $y''-4y=0$.

Its characteristic equation is given as $\lambda^2 - 4 = 0$. Then, we can easily get $\lambda_1=2$ and $\lambda_2=-2$. Accordingly, we finally get $$y=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-2x}. \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$

---

Now, let's use the power series method, rather than the characteristic equation. That is, we consider $y = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m x^m$. Then, naturally, $y''=\sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_m x^{m-2}$.
Then, from $y''-4y=0$, we have
\begin{align}
y''-4y &= \sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_m x^{m-2} - 4 \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m x^m\\
&= \sum_{m=2}^\infty m(m-1)a_m x^{m-2} - 4 \sum_{m=2}^\infty a_{m-2} x^{m-2}\\
&= \sum_{m=2}^\infty \Big( m(m-1)a_m - 4 a_{m-2} \Big) x^{m-2} \\
&= 0.\\
\end{align}
For the equality sign to be satisfied, $m(m-1)a_m - 4 a_{m-2} = 0$, resulting in the following recursive relation: $$ a_m = \frac{4a_{m-2}}{m(m-1)}.$$

From the above recursive relation, we can derive
\begin{equation}
a_{2k} = \frac{4^k a_0}{(2k)!}  \qquad  \text{and} \qquad a_{2k+1} = \frac{4^k a_1 }{(2k+1)!}.
\end{equation}

Finally, we can get
\begin{align}
y &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m x^m\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k} x^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k+1} x^{2k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k a_0}{(2k)!} x^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k a_1 }{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1} \\
&= a_0 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(2k)!} + \frac{a_1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}. \tag{2} \label{eq2}\\
\end{align}

---

Because both \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} are obtained from $y''-4y=0$, they should be the same. Hence, I tried to make them be the same, and finally knew that they are the same when $$a_0 = C_1+C_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad  \frac{a_1}{2} = 2(C_1-C_2).\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

---

Question) I used the Maclaurin series to expand \eqref{eq1} and, through comparison with \eqref{eq2}, I discovered \eqref{eq3}. I'm certain that if I didn't initially know \eqref{eq1}, I would never have been able to derive it from \eqref{eq2}. Is there a method to deduce \eqref{eq1} from \eqref{eq2}? Of course, using \eqref{eq3} makes the deduction from \eqref{eq2} to \eqref{eq1} straightforward, but finding the relationship like \eqref{eq3} without knowing \eqref{eq1} seems extremely challenging. I am curious if there exists a methodology to logically and forwardly progress through mathematical developments to deduce \eqref{eq1} from \eqref{eq2} without resorting to extraordinary guess or relationship like that of \eqref{eq3}.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}= \cosh(t)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \sinh(t)$ are "well-known" series.  You then have $\cosh(t) + \sinh(t) = e^t$ and $\cosh(t) - \sinh(t) = e^{-t}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you for giving me a very concise, accurate answer. By the way, can you please tell me another way of solution not using hyperbolic sinusoidal functions?